# ClosedChannel Exception

Tags: scala, jboss, netty

I have the following Scala code:

```
var cf:ChannelFuture = try {
  tlog().info(" Before Channel write ...........{} {}", _channel.isOpen, _channel.getConfig.getConnectTimeoutMillis)
  _channel.write(rsp) } catch {
  case e:ClosedChannelException => 
    tlog.error("ClosedChannelException thrown: NettyTrigger @line 97") 
    null
  case e:Throwable =>
    tlog.error("", e) 
    null
}

if (inp != null) try {
  tlog().info(" Before Channel if *** write ...........{} {}", _channel.isOpen, _channel.getConfig.getConnectTimeoutMillis)
  cf= _channel.write(new ChunkedStream(inp))
} catch {
  case e:ClosedChannelException => 
    tlog.error("ClosedChannelException thrown: NettyTrigger @line 107") 
  case e:Throwable =>
    tlog.error("", e) 
}
```

When we put load on our server It throw below error :

```
2014-11-30 23:22:38 [New I/O worker #12] ERROR c.z.blason.io.EventEmitter - 
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.discard(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:168) ~[netty-3.6.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.flush(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:192) ~[netty-3.6.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleDownstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:121) ~[netty-3.6.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:704) ~[netty-3.6.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:671) ~[netty-3.6.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:248) ~[netty-3.6.5.Final.jar:na]
    at com.zotoh.blason.io.NettyTrigger.reply(NettyTrigger.scala:97) ~[blason-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.zotoh.blason.io.NettyTrigger.resumeWithResult(NettyTrigger.scala:64) ~[blason-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.zotoh.blason.io.AsyncWaitEvent.resumeOnResult(AsyncWaitEvent.scala:40) ~[blason-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.zotoh.blason.io.AbstractEvent.setResult(AbstractEvent.scala:58) ~[blason-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.zotoh.blason.io.HTTPEvent.setResult(HTTPEvent.scala:76) ~[blason-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.narvar.services.tracking.AbstractCarrierService.htmlAsSingleTrack(AbstractCarrierService.scala:757) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.narvar.carriers.ups.tracking.CarrierService.com$narvar$carriers$ups$tracking$CarrierService$$onSingle(CarrierService.scala:76) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.narvar.carriers.ups.tracking.CarrierService$$anonfun$1.apply(CarrierService.scala:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.narvar.carriers.ups.tracking.CarrierService$$anonfun$1.apply(CarrierService.scala:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.narvar.services.tracking.AbstractCarrierService.evalStatus(AbstractCarrierService.scala:658) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.narvar.carriers.ups.tracking.CarrierService.processReply(CarrierService.scala:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.narvar.workflow.tracking.FormatResult$$anon$1.eval(FormatResult.scala:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.zotoh.blason.wflow.Work.perform(Work.scala:39) ~[blason-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.zotoh.blason.wflow.PTaskStep.eval(PTaskStep.scala:43) ~[blason-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.zotoh.blason.wflow.FlowStep.run(FlowStep.scala:101) ~[blason-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_17]
```

Why is it throwing this exception?

Answer (score 0):

`ClosedChannelException` here means that your write attempt has been failed because the channel has been closed.  Obviously, we cannot write to a closed channel.  Looking from the stack trace, `ChunkedWriteHandler.discard()` has marked the current write operation as failure because the current channel is not connected anymore.

To avoid this exception, you should not close the connection before everything is written out.

However, it's impossible practically because a connection can be closed due to many reasons and some of them are inevitable.  You'd better just write your code deal with that exception in a robust manner.  It's simply trying to tell you that the connection was closed before the transfer is finished.